# add Class after window.load to html element added by .load not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading a header with navigation menu using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').load("header.html");
});
```

and after this code I have the following

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#about').addClass('active');
});
```

from everything I understand, the `window.load` runs after `document.ready`, but it's still not applying anything. Any help? The jquery for `addClass` seems correct as when typed into a console after loading up the page in a browser, it works.

Is this a problem with the way I have set up my header template and loading it?

Previously I worked with php and some node.js, so re-using code was straightforward but I have a requirement to use pure html/js, hence the header template.

thanks

Comment: 'about' id is inside header.html file?

Comment: yes this is correct. apologies I should of made that clear

Comment: `.load` event does not fire on `$().load` - they might have the same name, but they're very different actions.

Answer (score 6):

Try doing it in the load call back instead:

```
$('#header').load("header.html", function () {
   // this is run after header.html has been loaded
   $('#about').addClass('active');
});
```

[More information about `.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass a callback to `load` which should run after the content has loaded

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').load("header.html", function(){
       $('#about').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

To understand the differences between document ready and window load check this: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)